Scrape contents of Network section of an element in a page
I need to scrape a page, the website is the following:
https://commercialisti.it/iscritti
It's only in italian but still, it is a list of professional people that I'm able to search via "Cap".
For example, by filling the Cap with the value 37138 and then pressing on "CERCA" it will display a list of professionals with a few data. I found that if I inspect the page, go to network and then on the element LstIscritti?_=1713434471262 there is a JSON with all the data that I need.
The problem is that I don't understand how to scrape by entering in this section of the website.
I tried with beautifulsoup but I'm only able to scrape the html of the main page
My code so far:
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://commercialisti.it/iscritti')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//iframe)[1]"))

casella_testo = driver.find_element("id", "Cap")
casella_testo.send_keys("37138")

pulsante_cerca = driver.find_element("id", 'btnContinua')
pulsante_cerca.click()


time.sleep(5)


res = driver.find_element("id", "listIscritti")

time.sleep(10)

The content of res is the scraped table displayed in the page after pressing "CERCA" button, but I need the details that are in the Network section


I need to scrape a page

I recommend using requests instead of selenium,
since cutting out the browser makes it a bit simpler.
It looks like pressing that first button sends a request that returns some session cookies.
After that you are allowed to make a second request for the data.
import requests
import time

# Request search
r = requests.get("https://ricerca.commercialisti.it/RicercaIscritti",
                 params={
                     "search": "True",
                     "ente": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                     "cap": 37138,
                     "sezione": 0
                 })

# Copy session cookies from the request
cookies = r.cookies

# Make a request for the data
r = requests.post("https://ricerca.commercialisti.it/RicercaIscritti/LstIscritti",
                  params={
                      "_": int(time.time()*1000)
                  },
                  allow_redirects=False,
                  cookies=cookies)

# Parse data in bs4 for later use
data = r.json()

# View data
import json
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

And the result looks like:
[
{
    "Id": "ee5bb9f7-b3c1-47ae-9bcb-41e27d25177a",
    "Nome": "BARBARA",
    "Cognome": "AGNELLI",
    "Ente": "Verona",
    "Comune": "NEGRAR",
    "UpdateDate": "2024-03-28T16:08:22.883",
    "Archived": false,
    "Radiato": false,
    "TotalRecords": 176,
    "Sezione": 0,
    "ComuneNascita": "VERONA",
    "DataNascita": "09/09/1971",
    "Sospeso": false,
    "Studio": "<i class=\"fa fa-map-marker\"></i> Via Garibba 2 37138 Verona (VR) <i class=\"fa fa-phone\"></i> 045568147 <i class=\"fa fa-fax\"></i> 045565677 <br/>",
    "IdSoggetto": 63936,
    "UrlIscritto": "/RicercaIscritti/Scheda/ee5bb9f7-b3c1-47ae-9bcb-41e27d25177a"
},
...
]

You can use the developer console in any browser or an external web debugging proxy like:
Charles, Burp Suite, mitmproxy, etc.
To find out how to recreate the requests that browsers make.
